# Get a color from Asset Catalog prior to OS X 10.13

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nscolor

For applications running on OS X 10.13 or later, you can use `[NSColor colorNamed:@"MyColor"]` to get a color from an asset catalog. But how can you access these colors in applications meant for **older OS versions**?

Experiments with `+colorWithCatalogName:colorName:` do not appear to work, it looks like you can only access system colors that way.

```
NSColor *someColor = [NSColor colorWithCatalogName:@"Assets.xcassets" colorName:@"FunkyColor"];
NSLog(@"Color: %@", someColor);
```

This yields "(null)".

Is there a way at all to access Asset Catalog colors pre-10.13?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any progress on this?

Comment: Nope, sorry - I had to work around this issue.

Comment: Do not use color set if your app need support macOS before 10.13. When use color set in xib, Xcode will show a warning: "Discouraged Configuration. Named colors are not fully dynamic prior to macOS 10.13, and only update when the Interface Builder document is saved."